# Стили для QAction Qt5 C++

Tags: c++, qt

Всем привет!

Хотел бы узнать, можно ли в меню задавать стили для каждого пункта отдельные стили?

Например есть QMenu  в котором много QAction, и хочется сделать в таблице стилей qss такую вещь, чтобы при наведении мышкой на определенные QAction их background-color подсвечивался разным цветом. Например некоторые подсвечивались синим, некоторые красным, а другие зеленым.

Я задаю стили ко всему меню в таблице через селектор:

## nameMenu::item:selected

так можно для всех QAction внутри одного QMenu одинаковые задать.

А если я захочу для некоторых QAction индивидуальные стили наложить? Пробовал давать им другие имена через setObjectName, но не получается применить стили.